# bash in TTY instead of zsh

Tags: bash, tty, zsh

Ok, ive installed oh-my-zsh and its nice and fancy, but when i switch to TTY, it complains that 256 colors are not supported and all powerline fonts are obviously messed up. Is there a way to set bash to be used in TTYs by default and how?

Comment: You could consider adding a conditional to your `~/.zshrc` that tests the terminal capabilities instead. Something like this maybe? [How do I change my oh-my-zsh theme when in TTY](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/9yfqyf/how_do_i_change_my_ohmyzsh_theme_when_in_tty/)

Comment: @steeldriver aha, i was thinking abt it, thanks, i will try

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded by inserting at the end of the `~/.zshrc` file the following command:

```
if [ `tput colors` != "256" ]; then
  exec bash -l;
fi
```

So, if the environment does not support 256 colors, bash is launched.